# How to track number of downloads in html audio tag

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am using html  tags for different events/talk shows on my website. Now I want to track how many people clicked on "Download Button" of Audio Tag. I went through various documentation and found some methods and events for Play, Pause, Seek etc but nothing for tracking "Download" in HTML. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to track download count in pure HTML. You'll need to apply other languages. Usually this is done with something like a JS event handler on the download link that sends an Ajax request to a PHP script which tracks downloads in a cache or database.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can accomplish this is to use a mixture of JavaScript and PHP (or any other programming language you'd like) and do something to the effect of this:

1. addEventListener to the play button in the HTML audio markup.
2. Create a callback that uses an Ajax request to a remote script (PHP file as an example, or something else).
3. Post to a file (again, count.php as an example).
4. The post to location then track the play count in a database.
5. Return a response back, either to notify the user or for debugging.

**Resources**:

- [addEventListener on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Ajax on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (*other Frameworks are available*)
- [Ajax and PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) on w3schools

**The flow**:

> **Listen for play click** >> **Fire Ajax request** >> **Log the play to a
>   database**.

Comment: It had event for Play. What I need is for Downloads